# how to implement on change notification on a object

Tags: c#, event-handling, onchange

I have a plain normal class, e.g.:

```
public class ObjectA
{
    public string val {get;set;}
    ...
}
```

in another class, it holds an instance of ObjectA, e.g.:

```
public class ObjectB
{
     private ObjectA objectA;
     ....
}
```

the instance "objectA" will be frequently changed.
i mean in ObjectB, some of the method will new and new instance of Object A and assign to "objectA"

is there a way to implement a trigger, whenever instance `objectA` is change, will allow me to do something, e.g.:

```
objectA += OnChanged_ObjectA   

protected void OnOnChanged_ObjectA()
{
    // do something
}
```

Comment: If `objectA` field is only changed by `ObjectB` internal methods, then you should already know when you change it (assuming code for `ObjectB` is written by you). Can you give more details of what you are trying to do?

Comment: You should implement the observer pattern. In C#, using events and delegates. http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternObserver.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a change [event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8627sbea.aspx) on `ObjectA` that you will fire for any of the changes you wish to track. This will allow you to subscribe to this event on any other object, including `ObjectB`.

In `Object1.cs`:

```
// Delegate type for the event handler
public delegate void MyEventHandler();

// Declare the event.
public event MyEventHandler MyEvent;

// In the properties or any place you what to notify of change:
if (MyEvent != null)
      MyEvent();
```

And in `Object2.cs` you can subscribe:

```
objectA.MyEvent += OnChanged_ObjectA


protected void OnOnChanged_ObjectA()
{
    // Action changes
}
```

Comment: @Oded I have a question, if i want to notify when a property changes, I have to raise the event of the setter of the property, right? For example: decimal Amount. Can you give me an example? I need this for WPF

Comment: @Andres - WPF has its own very different notification mechanisms. Not something that can be easily covered in a comment.

Comment: @Oded but cant i do the same with events? I need to call a method in a usercontrol when a object property changes that was declared inside of it..

Answer (score 3):

How about :
INotifyPropertyChanged Interface

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx

Comment: I believe this is more appropriate when using databinding with the class.

Answer (score 0):

I had such problem recently, but unfortunately, I didn't find any another solution, but this:

```
public ObjectB
{
    private ObjectA _objectA;
    public  ObjectA objectA
    {
        get 
        { 
            return _objectA; 
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != _objectA)
            {
                _objectA = value;
                RaiseObjectAChanged(/* sender, args */);
            }
        }
    }
    private RaiseObjectAChanged()
    {
        // raise event here
    }
    private OnObjectAChanged()
    {
        // event handler
    }
}
```

Comment: this is one solution... but lots of place are using it... if i make this change.. i need to go thought lots of code..

can i create an even instead???